# send id via url but hidden

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have an html link:

```
<a href="destination">Link</a>
```

I formatted the link destination with a htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^destination$ index.php?content=destination [L,NC,QSA]
```

The question is: How can I give a ID via URL to the destination?
the full link will be `index.php?content=destination?ID=x`
X will be a dynamic number

but I would like to show this in the url - it should be invisible.
But I don't know how I have to modify the rewriteRule to realize it.

Comment: So you don't want the ID to show in the URL but it will always be different?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: That does not make any sense. If the reference itself does not contain that ID, then where should it come from? A rewriting rule cannot make it up from thin air... What you _can_ do is this: you use a reference like `destination/5` or something similar. Then the information is part of the request and can be extracted and used by the rewriting rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not a pretty solution and it obviously comes with flaws, you could always use cookies.

set a cookie in PHP:

```
setcookie("page_id","987987");
```

and look for it in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^page_id=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^destination$ index.php?content=destination&id=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```